# Aurelia.io: Options for a Custom Attribute

Tags: aurelia

I use the jquery daterangepicker (http://www.daterangepicker.com/) inside a aurelia.io project.

```
import {inject, bindable, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';
import $ from 'jquery';

@customAttribute('daterange')
@inject(Element)
export class DateRangePicker {
 constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
 }
 attached() {
$(this.element).daterangepicker()
  .on('change', e => fireEvent(e.target, 'input'));

}

detached() {
$(this.element).daterangepicker('destroy')
  .off('change');
}
}

function createEvent(name) {
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent(name, true, true);
return event;
}

function fireEvent(element, name) {
var event = createEvent(name);
element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

How can I submit options for the daterangepicker inside the html file to the custom attribute?

Answer (score 2):

**datePickerCustomElement.js**

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class DatePickerCustomElement {

  @bindable optionA;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  bind() {
    this.optionA = this.optionA || this.element.getAttribute('optionA');
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<date-picker optionA="12"></date-picker>
<date-picker optionaA.bind="optionAValue"</date-picker>
```

I've written a pretty detailed blog on a pattern for accomplishing this here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Comment: Matthew, do you think you could help me with this question about Aurelia? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978120/how-can-i-configure-two-or-more-apps-in-aurelia-using-webpack